# Q model and or query giving incorrect result

Tags: django, django-q

I want  perform below SQL query using Q models

> SELECT * FROM motor_vehicle_collision.collision_data_collisiondetails
> where (numberOfCyclistInjured > 0 or numberOfCyclistKilled > 0)  and
> (longitude != '' and latitude != '');

for that I have written below query

```
   query = Q(numberOfCyclistInjured__gt=0)
    query.add(Q(numberOfCyclistKilled__gt=0), Q.OR)
    query.add(~Q(latitude=''), Q.AND)
    query.add(~Q(longitude=''), Q.AND)
```

but still I am getting data having latitude/longitude empty, how should I rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with:

```
query = (Q(numberOfCyclistInjured__gt=0) | Q(numberOfCyclistKilled__gt=0))
    & ~Q(longitude='')
    & ~Q(latitude=''))
```

This makes it also more explicit how you bind the conditions together.

Comment: I think there should be bracket before  ~Q(longitude='') ?

Comment: @LowCool: normally not, since `~` takes precedence over `&`.